# Lazarus 0.9.30.2 How to destroy a dynamically created TMySQL51Connection? ERROR

Tags: mysql, lazarus

I had lazarus 0.9.30 installed on the desktop and on the notebook (Windows 7 and MySQL 5.5.13 on both).

I was using TMySQL50connection without problems.

on few weeks ago i upgraded my notebook to lazarus 0.9.30.2 and, on the same project, without any modifications on the code (i only changed TMySQL50connection to TMySQL51connection) i began to have the following error when i run the project inside lazarus

Debugger Exception Notification   Project Controle de Processos raised exception class 'EDatabaseError' with message Operation cannot be performed on an active transaction

When i run the .exe from Windows Explorer it runs without error.

After some days without a solution i uninstalled lazarus 0.9.30.2 and came back to lazarus 0.9.30 and back my code to TMySQL50connection, but for my surprise the error message persists.

So now i have lazarus 0.9.30 on both machines, with the same project (same code). On my desktop i don't have any errors, everything is Ok, but on my notebook i have the error message above.

What can i do ??????

I need some help !!!!!

How to completely remove lazarus 0.9.30.2 and go back to lazarus 0.9.30 ?

(I don't remember if i have applied some patch on my desktop)

Thank you very much in advance

The line that causes the error is     TranCli.Free;

The code is:

```
try
  ConCli := TMySQL50Connection.Create(nil);
  ConCli.HostName := ipHost;
  ConCli.port := 3306;
  ConCli.UserName := username;
  ConCli.Password := password;
  ConCli.DatabaseName := databasename;
  TranCli := TSQLTransaction.Create(nil);
  TranCli.DataBase := ConCli;
  QryCli := TSQLQuery.Create(nil);
  QryCli.DataBase := ConCli;
  QryCli.Transaction := TranCli;
  try
    ConCli.Open;
  except
    on e : exception do
    begin
      if (e.Message='Server connect failed.') then
      begin
        MessageDlg('Error',
            'Could not connect server.',mtError,
             [mbCancel],0);
        exit;
      end;
    end;
  end;

  ...

  Code here

  ...

finally
  QryCli.Close;
  ConCli.Close;
  QryCli.Free;
  TranCli.Free;
  ConCli.Free;
end;
```

How to solve this ?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you somehow have to make the transaction not active too. .active property, or disconnecting it from the query?